# entity framework Where method

Tags: c#, linq, entity

i need some help in this , how do i write a where clause statement where i want to retrieve record based on 2 columns :

This is how i am trying to write in code :

```
public IList<Model.question> GetAll(string search , int search1)
{
    IList<Model.question> lstQuestions = context.questions.ToList();
    return lstQuestions.Where(a => a.TaskName.Contains(search) && p => p.ActivityID.Contains(search1)).ToList(); 
}
```

but there is an error with this statement .

----- ABOVE SOLVED ------------

Heres another problem :

```
 public int GetMaxValue(string listTask , int listActivity)
    {

        int maxQNo = Convert.ToInt32(context.questions.Max(q => q.QuestionNo).Where(q.TaskName.Contains(listTask) && q.ActivityID == listActivity));

        return maxQNo+1;
    }
```

i get the error where q doesn't exist is current context , what i am trying to do here , is to get the max value of the column ( questionNo) where taskname = list task and activityid = list activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public IList<Model.question> GetAll(string search , int search1)
    {
        IList<Model.question> lstQuestions = context.questions.ToList();
        return lstQuestions.Where(a => a.TaskName.Contains(search) && a.ActivityID==search1)).ToList(); 
    }
```

**Answer of new problem:**

Add `q =>` block in `Where` clause.

```
public int GetMaxValue(string listTask , int listActivity)
{

    int maxQNo = Convert.ToInt32(context.questions.Max(q => q.QuestionNo)
                                                  .Where(q=>q.TaskName.Contains(listTask) && 
                                                         q.ActivityID.Contains(listActivity));

    return maxQNo+1;
}
```

Comment: Hi there , thanks for the fast reply , but my ActivityID is a INT in db , i tried to use int search1 but it gives me an error  Instance argument: cannot convert from 'int?' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<int>' and 'int?' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @user2376998: if `ActivityID` is `INT` then why your `search1` variable is `string`? it should be also `INT`? Right?

Comment: yeah sorry , forgot to changed it

Comment: @user2376998: I've updated my answer. `Contains` is replaced by `==`. Please check now.

Comment: hi there , thanks for the answer , but i got another question to ask u , duno if its appropriate , sorry if it is ... new to stackoverflow .... the question is updated above.. hope u can take a look thanks

Comment: @user2376998: Please post a new question since the new problem is not relevant to the old one. It should be like that. btw, I am trying to give you an insight into the problem in my answer.