# find max value of columns using where method

Tags: c#, entity

Heres another problem :

```
 public int GetMaxValue(string listTask , int listActivity)
{

    int maxQNo = Convert.ToInt32(context.questions.Max(q => q.QuestionNo).Where(q.TaskName.Contains(listTask) && q.ActivityID == listActivity));

    return maxQNo+1;
}
```

i get the error where q doesn't exist is current context , what i am trying to do here , is to get the max value of the column ( questionNo) where taskname = list task and activityid = list activity.

Comment: you haven't specified q as the input of your where lambda

Comment: @user2376998: I've already answer in your old post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888868/entity-framework-where-method

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Don't you want `.Max()` after `.Where()`? `.Max()` executes query immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is a little off: you need to add `q =>` to the `Where` function, and change the order of the functions so that `Max` is the last function in the chain,

```
int maxQNo = Convert.ToInt32(
    context
        .questions
        .Where(q => q.TaskName.Contains(listTask) && q.ActivityID == listActivity)
        .Max(q => q.QuestionNo)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put `q =>` in the `Where` statment

Answer (score 0):

Add `q =>` block in `Where` clause And also you need to replace `==` by `Contains` since you are using list now.

```
public int GetMaxValue(string listTask , int listActivity)
{

    int maxQNo = Convert.ToInt32(context.questions.Max(q => q.QuestionNo)
                                                  .Where(q=>q.TaskName.Contains(listTask) && 
                                                         q.ActivityID.Contains(listActivity));

    return maxQNo+1;
}
```